# Accessing Singleton object in SetUpTestCase method of google test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, singleton, googletest

When I try to access the singleton object in SetUpTestCase() of googlet test, I get error as cannot call member function without object.

The Singleton pattern code is as follows

```
class Singleton final
{
public:
    static Singleton& GetInstance();
    
private:
    Singleton() = default;
    ~Singleton() = default;

    // Delete the copy and move constructors 
    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton(Singleton&&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(Singleton&&) = delete;
};
    
Singleton& Singleton::GetInstance()
{
    static Singleton instance;
    return instance;
}
```

So in google test I am trying to access the object in SetUpTestCase as follows

```
class X: public testing::Test
{
public:
    static void SetUpTestCase()
    {
        Singleton& s = Singleton::GetInstance();
    }
};
```

Error: cannot call member function Singleton& Singleton::GetInstance() without object

Comment: The error message suggests that in the actual code you compile, `GetInstance` is not in fact marked `static`.

Comment: I thought it was something to do with google test, since it was working fine in source code. Thanks for pointing out the error.